# Find the Emirps!

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes, base-conversion, integer

> An [**emirp**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirp) is a ***non-palindromic*** prime which, when reversed, is also prime.

The list of base 10 emirps can be found on [**OEIS**](http://oeis.org/A006567). The first six are:

```
13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73
```

However, due to the reversal rule, emirps are different in each base. For example, the first six binary emirps are:

```
Bin  | 1011, 1101, 10111, 11101, 101001, 100101
Dec  | (11 , 13  , 23   , 29   , 37    , 41   )
```

...and in hexadecimal, they are:

```
Hex |  17, 1F, 35, 3B, 3D, 53
Dec | (23, 31, 53, 59, 61, 83)
```

<sub>Fun Fact: there are no emirps in [unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system) as every number is a palindrome.</sub>

---

## The Challenge

Your task is to create a function (or full program) which takes two parameters,
\$ n \$ and \$ b \$, and generates a list of the first \$ n \$ emirps in base \$ b \$.

**Rules/Details:**

- \$ n \$ and \$ b \$ are both positive integers larger than \$ 0 \$.
- You can assume \$ 2 ≤ b ≤ 16 \$: that is to say, the base will be between binary and hexidecimal.
- You should be able to compute for values of \$ n \$ up to \$ ~100 \$.
- The generated list can be in base \$ b \$, or your language's standard integer base, as long as you specify this in your answer.
- Builtin emirp checks are not permitted (builtin primality tests are fine)
- You cannot hard-code the emirps, or read from any external files.
- Standard loopholes are banned, as always.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

---

## Test Cases

For each test case, I've included the list in base `b` and its base 10 equivalents.

```
B = 2, N = 10

BIN: [1011, 1101, 10111, 11101, 100101, 101001, 101011, 101111, 110101, 111101]
DEC: [11, 13, 23, 29, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 61] 


B = 3, N = 5

BASE3: [12, 21, 102, 201, 1011]
DEC:   [5, 7, 11, 19, 31]


B = 12, N = 7

BASE12: [15, 51, 57, 5B, 75, B5, 107]
DEC: [17, 61, 67, 71, 89, 137, 151]


B = 16, N = 4

HEX: [17, 1F, 35, 3B]
DEC: [23, 31, 53, 59]
```

You can test your program further against my (ungolfed) Python example on [**repl.it**](https://repl.it/EPmq/1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
bµU,ḅ⁹QÆPḄ=3
⁸ç#
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YsK1VSzhuIXigblRw4ZQ4biEPTMK4oG4w6cj&input=&args=MTY+Ng)**

#### How?

```
bµU,ḅ⁹QÆPḄ=3 - Link 1, in-sequence test: n, b
b            - convert n to base b - a list
 µ           - monadic chain separation
  U          - reverse the list
   ,         - pair with the list
     ⁹       - link's right argument, b
    ḅ        - convert each of the two lists from base b
      Q      - get unique values (if palindromic a list of only one item)
       ÆP    - test if prime(s) - 1 if prime, 0 if not
         Ḅ   - convert to binary
          =3 - equal to 3? (i.e. [reverse is prime, forward is prime]=[1,1])

⁸ç# - Main link: b, N
  # - count up from b *see note, and find the first N matches (n=b, n=b+1, ...) for:
 ç  - last link (1) as a dyad with left argument n and right argument
⁸   - left argument, b
```

* Note `b` in base `b` is `[1,0]`, which when reversed is `[0,1]` which is `1`, which is not prime; anything less than `b` is one digit in base `b` and hence palindromic.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

Uses [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com) encoding.

Input order is `n, b`
Output is in base-10.

```
µN²BÂD²öpŠÊNpPD–½
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wrVOwrJCw4JEwrLDtnDFoMOKTnBQROKAk8K9&input=NwoxMg)

**Explanation**

```
                    # implicit input a,b
µ                   # loop until counter is a
 N²B                # convert current iteration number to base b
    ÂD              # create 2 reversed copies
      ²ö            # convert one reversed copy to base 10
        p           # check for primality
         ŠÊ         # compare the normal and reversed number in base b for inequality
           Np       # check current iteration number for primality
             P      # product of all
              D     # duplicate
               –    # if 1, print current iteration number
                ½   # if 1, increase counter
```

Comment: You can drop the trailing `½`, since it's done implicitly (not sure if this was already the case when you posted this answer, probably not).

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 70 bytes

```
Cases[Prime@Range@437,p_/;(r=p~IntegerReverse~#2)!=p&&PrimeQ@r]~Take~#&
```

Works for `0 <= n <= 100` and `2 <= b <= 16`. From the list `Prime@Range@437` of the first `437` primes, find the `Cases` `p`where the `IntegerReverse` `r` of `p` in base `#2` is not equal to `p` and is also prime, then take the first `#` such `p`.

Here's a 95 byte solution that works for arbitrary `n>=0` and `b>=2`:

```
(For[i=1;a={},Length@a<#,If[(r=IntegerReverse[p=Prime@i,#2])!=p&&PrimeQ@r,a~AppendTo~p],i++];a)&
```

Comment: +1 `IntegerReverse`.  Of course! Nice.

Comment: [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98tvyg60zbL1kAny0ZZxzMtWqPI1jOvJDU9tSgotSy1qDg1usA2oCgzN9VBWztTR9koVlPRtkBNDSwU6FCkk6WtbQ3k5JU4FMTGqv1PizbRMTSL/Q8A) for the arbitrary-n-b solution; [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcixCsIwEADQX1EKQckNtoiLHmQSumkdjxuCXDSBtOEM@vlRfOPLvj4l@xrvvoUVtvOiFDHhDtKpgzHQRnGcqzxEJ3mLvoQKXjRmcdZG6AberrEY86@rU0jWHm/LxxVm0347V5rEFwq0h/7ATDRAz8ztCw) if `Reap`ing is allowed in the footer: `For[i=j=0,j<#,If[(r=IntegerReverse[p=Prime@++i,#2])!=p&&PrimeQ@r,j++;Sow@p]]&`

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 262 bytes

```
($b,$n)=@ARGV;$,=',';sub c{my$z;for($_=pop;$_;$z=(0..9,a..z)[$_%$b].$z,$_=($_-$_%$b)/$b){};$z}sub d{my$z;for(;c(++$z)ne@_[0];){}$z}for($p=2;@a<$n;$p++){$r=qr/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/;(c($p)eq reverse c$p)||((1x$p)=~$r)||(1x d($x=reverse c($p)))=~$r?1:push@a,c($p);}say@a
```

Readable:

```
($b,$n)=@ARGV;
$,=',';
sub c{
    my$z;
    for($_=pop;$_;$z=(0..9,a..z)[$_%$b].$z,$_=($_-$_%$b)/$b){};
    $z
}
sub d{
    my$z;
    for(;c(++$z)ne@_[0];){}
    $z
}
for($p=2;@a<$n;$p++){
    $r=qr/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/;
    (c($p)eq reverse c$p)||((1x$p)=~$r)||(1x d($x=reverse c($p)))=~$r?1:push@a,c($p)
}
say@a
```

`c` converts a given number into base `$b`, and `d` converts a given number from base `$b` back into decimal by finding the first number which returns said base-`$b` number when passed to `c`.  The for loop then checks if it's a palindrome and if both of the numbers are prime using the composite regex.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 112 bytes

```
Cases[Table[Prime@n~IntegerDigits~#2,{n,500}],x_/;x!=(z=Reverse@x)&&PrimeQ[z~(f=FromDigits)~#2]:>x~f~#2]~Take~#&
```

---

**Example**

Find the first 10 Emips in hex; return them in decimal.

```
Cases[Table[Prime@n~IntegerDigits~#2, {n, 500}], 
x_ /; x != (z = Reverse@x) && PrimeQ[z~(f = FromDigits)~#2] :> x~f~#2]~Take~# &[10, 16]


{23, 31, 53, 59, 61, 83, 89, 113, 149, 179}
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```
Take[Cases[                                             (* take #1 cases; #1 is the first input argument *)
   Table[IntegerDigits[Prime[n], #2], {n, 500}],        (* from a list of the first 500 primes, each displayed as a list of digits in base #2 [second argument] *) 
   x_ /;                                                (* x, a list of digits, such that *)
   x != (z = Reverse[x]) && PrimeQ[FromDigits[z, #2]]   (* the reverse of the digits is not the same as the list of digits; and the reverse list, when composed, also constitutes a prime *)
   :> FromDigits[x, #2]],                               (* and return the prime *)
   #1] &                                                (* [this is where #1 goes, stating how many cases to Take] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 91 bytes

```
->\n,\b{(grep {.is-prime&&{$_ ne.flip &&.parse-base(b).is-prime}(.base(b).flip)},1..*)[^n]}
```

Returns the list of emirps in base 10.

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##JclBCsIwFEXRuat4gxKSkgSr2IGiG7FaEviRQBs/yaiUrj2iDu@5THnq67xABFxRzW1IevCrfGVirM2IRDZMkYWIxXCOM4FdLmS8K4RmFL@LM/z2bu0XpVe6s7ZV92d6bLW4BUF2e31Ql90/Tvqo6gc)

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>293</s> <s>286</s> 261 bytes

Improved by [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat), 261 bytes:

```c
v,t,i,j,c,g,s[9],r[9],b;main(n,a)int**a;{for(b=n=atoi(a[1]);g^atoi(a[2]);t|v|!wcscmp(s,r)||printf("%u ",n,++g)){i=j=0;for(c=++n;s[i]=c;c/=b)s[i++]=c%b+1;for(;r[j]=i;)r[j++]=s[--i];p(n);for(t=v;r[i];)c+=~-r[i]*pow(b,i++);p(c);}}p(n){for(j=1,v=0;++j<n;n%j||v++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7RasUgDIZfZTtQ0BrZOsaB4nyOXZQObEZFaW2pnp6LY/foc1p2k@RPvvwJco2Y0g4BDFhA0OC7toethEHMyjjiQFHjQl0r8RiXjQzSSRUWQ1TX9FTor3/xlkWIe3y@o8d5JR42GuO65d2RXKrb0wUcMKYpfRhp5asoZigZc8J3ppco8EUONNeMZVUNrDkRsXW2l0bQnMvEd5ybXqzE0XMe5J6R3KHI5A8vZb0udzJANqKZQyqOo@Dn@1Y2sOfrjNkPJ1xlY9wLd6SUmmt6/8VxUtonPs2Jf7qFm3mdDJqQuA/fUrtb2/4B)

(This person is like constantly following me around PPCG and improving my stuff in the comments, and as soon as I reply to thank him he just deletes the comment and vanishes lol. Welp, thanks again!)

---

Improved by [@movatica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86751/movatica), 286 bytes:

```c
u,v,t,i,j,c,n,g;main(int x,char**a){char s[9],r[9],b=n=atoi(a[1]);x=atoi(a[2]);for(;g^x;){i=j=0;for(c=++n;c;c/=b)s[i++]=c%b+1;s[i]=c=0;for(;i;r[j++]=s[--i]);r[j]=0;p(n);t=v;for(;r[i];)c+=(r[i]-1)*pow(b,i++);p(c);t|v|!strcmp(s,r)?:printf("%u ",n,++g);}}p(n){for(u=1,v=0;++u<n;n%u?:v++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/daoQwEIVfxS4IySahtZRCdxr2MXohFnRAG9EoSbSC66s3nfTnZjhn5sw3DKoOMcZFrjJII3uJ0soOxtpYZmzINokftTufa74nkfnypZIulUZbXYfJsLosKg7bv3kk006OQfe@Ad@N7vXDTwO1EBYQ8F433JdGiEpj3ogCyJD8i4EBV/Zp6EulDNHIVjScmeUQ9PqbcrQDHIVmSamCn@fpkzWSsJyiSNHbervzweE4My8dv15mRy@17JQv2YneFKLjcByJuyfmogu50iEhllcLNl@ulzXRjhhj8RyfvrAd6s5HNYxRvdlJmXEeDJrwDQ)

---

My original answer, 293 bytes:

```c
u,v,t,i,j,c,n,g;main(int x,char**a){char s[9],r[9],b=n=atoi(a[1]);x=atoi(a[2]);for(++n;g^x;++n){i=j=0;for(c=n;c;c/=b)s[i++]=c%b+1;s[i]=c=0;for(;i;r[j++]=s[--i]);r[j]=0;p(n);t=v;for(--i;r[++i];)c+=(r[i]-1)*pow(b,i);p(c);t|v|!strcmp(s,r)?:printf("%u ",n,++g);}}p(n){for(u=1,v=0;++u<n;n%u?:v++);}
```

Compile with `gcc emirp.c -o emirp -lm` and run with `./emirp <b> <n>`. Prints space-separated emirps in base-10.

Comment: @FlipTack You're right. I'll have to fix it tomorrow.

Comment: @FlipTack Fixed and tested to make sure it passes your tests. Is this good?

Comment: Sure is! And welcome to code golf.

Comment: Nice work! I moved some increment operators to get you down to [286](http://bit.ly/2Ryoukp)

Comment: @movatica Awesome! I added your improvements to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Suggest `s[i]=c?c%b+1:0;c/=b)i++;` instead of `s[i]=c;c/=b)s[i++]=c%b+1;` and `r[j++]=i?s[--i]:0;);` instead of `r[j]=i;)r[j++]=s[--i];`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>232</s> <s>214</s> <s>191</s> 188 bytes

- [Herman L](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70894/herman-l) -14 bytes
- [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) -3 bytes

```python
p=lambda n:all(n%i for i in range(2,n))
def f(b,n):
 s=lambda n:(''if n<b else s(n//b))+f'{n%b:X}';l=[];i=3
 while n:i+=1;c=s(i);d=c[::-1];a=(c!=d)*p(i)*p(int(d,b));l+=[c]*a;n-=a
 return l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9NboMwEIX3nGKqKsIOjoJxCRKuNyx6hkooCwOmseQ6CKiqqurZ6QAhWXje/HzzNO5@xsvVi2nqlNOfVaPB59o54ncW2msPFqyHXvsPQxLmKQ0a00JLKszzAIbHEglD24J/rcC4wcBA/PFYURq14a/fVfn7XyidKs/SKhHA98U6g0s2UlzWaiCWykbVZZ4f@FlqReon1dB9h/05@JE0DM2ki1RZn/da@oPSAfRm/Oo9uKnrZ6YlPGYnSuEZuGDAMwaC40PNUDMRbFzCeLxyMccJR2FLvhS3Kt668aZ8o2478Yqj3p0FS1fjhEGy4HOy2d8xHGcrlzJIcZrikWmBR2JdpDOdPeATe1lhhPgb/ggBUUz/)

Comment: [200 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY9NboMwEIX3nGKqqsIuToNxHSSoNyx6hkooC37sxpLjIKCqqqpnpwOEZGG/Gb9vnsbdz3i6eDFNnXLVuW4r8FnlHPFPFsylBwvWQ1/5T00S5ikNWm3AkBrrLIDhPkTCEKwB/1aDdoOGgfj9vqY0Cn@zj7/wBcPO1Yi5Nc2dKo@5VSKA75N1GqcDABspnjdqIJbmrWrKLNvx4/xuSPOgWvrcoTNffiQtw@TMRapsjrnfKR5Ar8ev3oObun4mDOExO1AKj8AFA54yEBwPaoqaimDjEsbjlYs5OhyFLfXSXLt4e4035Rt1nYlXHPWWLJhcgxMGyYLPxRZ/w9BOV04ykOhKXFIWuCT2hZzp9A4f2OsKI8Tf8UcIiGL6Bw)

Comment: Nice catch! Brought that down to [191 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY9NboMwEIX3PsVUVYRdHAXjOkhQb1j0DJVQFvw5seQ6CKiqqurZ6QAhWdhvxu@bp3H3M16uXk5Tp135WTUl@LR0jvqdBXPtwYL10Jf@3NKYe8ZI0xowtMI6JTA8hmgQWAP@rYLWDS0M1B8OFWOhCX79rko//oLM6eKUWS0JfF@sa3GIANhQi6zWA7Usa3RdpOlenOZ3Q@sn3bCXDp358iNtOCamLtRFfcr8XgsCfTt@9R7c1PUzYaiI@JExeAYhOYiEgxR4UBPURJKNi7mIVi4S6AgUvtRLc@ui7TXaVGzUbSZacdR7suRqDY45xAs@F1v8HUM7WTnFQaGrcEmV45LY52qmkwd85K8rjJB4xx8hIPPpHw)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>149</s> <s>148</s> <s>141</s> 140 bytes

Returns a space-separated list of emirps in base b. (Could be 2 bytes shorter by returning a decimal list instead.)

```js
f=(b,n,i=2)=>n?((p=(n,k=n)=>--k<2?k:n%k&&p(n,k))(i)&p(k=parseInt([...j=i.toString(b)].reverse().join``,b))&&k-i&&n--?j+' ':'')+f(b,n,i+1):''
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(b,n,i=2)=>n?((p=(n,k=n)=>--k<2?k:n%k&&p(n,k))(i)&p(k=parseInt([...j=i.toString(b)].reverse().join``,b))&&k-i&&n--?j+' ':'')+f(b,n,i+1):''

console.log(f(2,10));
console.log(f(3,5));
console.log(f(12,7));
console.log(f(16,4));
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 133 bytes

```python
p=lambda n:all(n%i for i in range(2,n))
b,n=input()
i=b
while n:
 j=i=i+1;r=0
 while j:r=r*b+j%b;j/=b
 if(i-r)*p(i)*p(r):print i;n-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvBCoMwEAXv@Yq9CIlGqh6V/ZiEan0hXcNiKf361NLLHIaZ8jn3Q6ZaC@fwjPdAMoecrTSg7VACQUiDPFY7eXHORC8MKa/TOgOO5r0jr9dkKDEY3bgoD4b@Os3K2sYuNXFJt6smbBa9urZY/KBuLgo5CYv0PNY6@XEYvg)

Outputs each number on a new line, in base 10

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>20</s></sup>  17 bytes

```
↑fo§&ȯṗB⁰↔S≠↔B⁰İp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxLT8Q8vVTqx/uHO606PGDY/apgQ/6lwApEC8IxsK/v//b/Tf0AAA)

The type inference is odd here.

-3 bytes from Jo King.

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 87 chars, 174 bytes

```
r←a f w;i
i←1⋄r←⍬
→2×⍳∼{∼0π⍵:0⋄k≡v←⌽k←{(a⍴⍨⌊1+a⍟⍵)⊤⍵}⍵:0⋄0πa⊥v:1⋄0}i+←1⋄r←r,i⋄→2×⍳w>≢r
```

The result will be in base 10. Test and results:

```
  3 f 1
5 
  2 f 10
11 13 23 29 37 41 43 47 53 61 
  3 f 5
5 7 11 19 31 
  12 f 7
17 61 67 71 89 137 151 
  16 f 4
23 31 53 59
```

`{(⍺⍴⍨⌊1+⍺⍟⍵)⊤⍵}` would do conversion of `⍵` in base `⍺`, array integer result; `0π⍵` would return true[1] if `⍵` is prime else it would return 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

With decimal output.

```
È2¶[XXìV'w]â xj}jU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yDK2W1hY7FYnd13iIHhqfWpV&input=NgoxNg)